# How to get value based on input of text field

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-services

Basically, I m trying to create a money converter with web services and with this code, it gives me a value of 1 figure for example if I select From GB to USD then it will calculate as 1 GB = 1 USD. But what I want is that I want to put a value on text box somehow which then should be converted e.g. if I insert a value 20 and select from GB to USD then should give me the result of 20 GB = anything USD.
Please help me solve this problem and help is appreciated.

```
currencyconv.CurrencyConvertor cc = new currencyconv.CurrencyConvertor();

currencyconv.Currency currenFrom = 
    (currencyconv.Currency)Enum.Parse(typeof(currencyconv.Currency), 
    dd1From.SelectedValue);

currencyconv.Currency currencyTo = 
    (currencyconv.Currency)Enum.Parse(typeof(currencyconv.Currency), 
    dd1To.SelectedValue);

double iRate = cc.ConversionRate(currenFrom, currencyTo);

lblConversion.Text = string.Format("1 {0} = {1} {2}", currenFrom, iRate, currencyTo);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what you've posted, you should add a `TextBox` to your form called something like `txtQuantity`, which only allows numeric input. Then you would do something like:

```
double quantity = double.Parse(txtQuantity.Text);

lblConversion.Text = string.Format("{0} {1} = {2} {3}",
    quantity, currenFrom, iRate * quantity, currencyTo);
```

Comment: Tnx Mate Really Appreciate your help